# Convert PSD files to Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, psd

Trying to figure out the best way to integrate a custom app design (psd files) into a Xamarin app. I know there is PaintCode but was wondering whether there is a different way e.g. using the iOS designer?

Comment: are the psd files a graphic? are they a screen design?

Comment: We do it using Paintcode & paintcode2skia converter. Then it's easy to use it in xamarin. I didn't find better way, but will watch this q. Disclaimer: I've put paintcode2skia to github

Answer (score 1):

Use the interface builder in XCode or Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio. As in, build it the "old fashioned" way: build the app one screen at a time in the interface builder, and use graphic assets from the PSD as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If the PSD files are a screen layout design, then you need to recreate the design using real interface elements in the Xamarin.Forms design tool... The psd files are just the files output to save your Photoshop image. They do not contain enough information to create an interface from they are just a visualization.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Adobe XD and then get export to Zepline.
you can export xamarin forms (xaml) export from Zeplin

Comment: Can you submit an example and image on how to do that?